# MongoDB: geospatial query with additional conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

```
{ _id : ObjectId(...),
  name : "...",
  addresses : [ {
                 context : "home" ,
                 loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
                } ,
                {
                 context : "office",
                 loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
                }
              ]
}
```

address.loc is "2d" indexed.

I want to write a query that should give me all the document that are $near a location and the context is office.

```
I wrote some thing like:
   db.coll.find({'address.loc':{$near:[lat,lng]}, 'address.context' : "office"});
```

Above query doesn't give me results that wanted. It searches for location in the entire "Address" array and then searches for context in the entire array.

I would like to search for same array location and same context. I know it could be done by $elemMatch but when I try to use it, it says there is no 2d index available or 2dsphere index.

I am new to MongoDB and not sure how should I write my query.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried the query and it seems to work as you intend with the $elemMatch operator. I think the problem is that you have a typo in your query where `address` is used instead of `addresses`. Your query should look like:

```
db.coll.find({ 'addresses.loc':{$near:[lat,lng]}, addresses: { $elemMatch: {context: "office"} } });
```

Comment: Thank you Philiq for the response but it seems that right now it is not supported. The above query will return results but the results are not correct. There are couple of JIRA tickets opened SERVER-3325 with MongoDB. I am not able to find others. There is no typo because I get results but results are not valid